# IO Ввод вывод c#

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, растолкуйте пожалуйста новичку по вводу выводу такие вопросы:

1. Вот я обнаружил, что `Console.Out` возвращает тип `TextWriter`, но как, если `TextWriter` это абстрактный класс ?
2. Далее `Console.WriteLine()`, на самом деле вызывает `Console.Out.WriteLine()`, но каким образом `Console.WriteLine()` передает данные `Console.Out` если там только есть геттер ?
3. Почему-то не могу въехать в чем отличие байтового потока от символьного, мне показалось что на выходы везде получается символьный поток.
4. Как понять фразу, для вывода символьного потока `FileStream` ЗАКЛЮЧАЕТСЯ В ОБОЛОЧКУ `StreamWriter`. Не пойму, что значит заключается в оболочку ?
   Спасибо, всем кто готов помочь. Завис я на этой теме

Comment: Хм. Байтовый поток — это поток байт, символьный — символов. Фразу «на выходы везде получается символьный поток» не понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, всё просто же.

1. На самом деле свойство выдаёт экземпляр не абстрактного `System.IO.TextWriter`, а конкретного `System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter`. Получается то же самое, как если бы вы написали `object o = new string()`: в декларации тип-предок (который вполне может быть абстрактным), реально — тип-потомок.
2. Для того, чтобы передать что-то объекту, нужен лишь getter для этого объекта. Смотрите:

   ```
   public static void WriteLine(int x)
   {
       var out = Console.Out; // это getter
       out.WriteLine(x);
   }
   ```

   или просто

   ```
   public static void WriteLine(int x)
   {
       Console.Out // это getter
              .WriteLine(x);
   }
   ```